# Can I save my spark trooper with a delayed flicker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What exactly defines the beginning and end of a specific step? Because I'm wondering if my logic seems solid enough.

I'm thinking of trying to avoid the sac requirement on my [Spark Trooper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Trooper) by using [Voidwalk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidwalk) or the ability of [Mistmeadow Witch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mistmeadow%20Witch) or the like. This way I hope that when he comes back to the field since all the initial actions that stated at the beginning of the end step resolve, it is thus no longer the beginning of said step meaning I can hopefully bypass the sac requirement when he re-enters and thus use spark trooper repeatedly without having to revive him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter when the beginning or end of a specific step is. The rules state that any permanents that trigger during the End Step, do not trigger until the next end step. This means that if you exile [Spark Trooper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Trooper) with [Mistmeadow Witch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mistmeadow%20Witch) in response to the sacrifice trigger, it will be removed until your opponents EOT, and you won't have to sacrifice it until your next end step. [Voidwalk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidwalk), due to it being a Sorcery, would require you casting it during the Second Main Phase, so you would need to save the targeted Spark Trooper at the end of your opponents turn as well.

> 513.3. If a permanent with an ability that triggers "at the beginning of the end step" enters the battlefield during this step, that ability won't trigger until the next turn's end step. Likewise, if a delayed triggered ability that triggers "at the beginning of the next end step" is created during this step, that ability won't trigger until the next turn's end step. In other words, the step doesn't "backup" so those abilities can go on the stack. This rule applies only to triggered abilities; it doesn't apply to continuous effects whose durations say "until end of turn" or "this turn." (See rule 514, "Cleanup Step.")

Comment: ok from what I've gathered I can do that to avoid it thank you for the reply

Comment: @user1875, I think you meant "you won't have to sacrifice it until your **next** end step" or "you won't have to sacrifice it **in** your opponents end step".

Comment: @Pablo, no I didn't. Voidwalk is a sorcery, so barring some other trickery, Spark Trooper would be cast during their Main Phase, and would normally be sacked at their EOT. In response, they could blink it out with Mistmeadow Witch during their EOT step, or they could blink it with Voidwalk during the 2nd Main Phase. In either case, the Spark Trooper will need to be rescued again, or it will be sacked **during** their opponents EOT. The OP needs to save Spark Trooper at the **end of every turn**, not just their own.

Comment: Actually, if you blink the Spark Trooper with Mistmeadow Witch in response to its trigger, it would return the Trooper to the battlefield at the beginning of your opponent's end step, which means it wouldn't be sacrificed again until the end step of your next turn. But you're right about Voidwalk of course.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, duly noted and corrected. I forgot about the duration of the exile from Mistmweadow Withes effect.

Answer (score 2):

As with every other step, the beginning of the End Step is the instant the End Step begins. If something has happened in the End Step, it's past the beginning of the End Step.

In the scenario you presented, the following has happened in the End Step before [Spark Trooper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Trooper) entered the 'field:

- The delayed triggered ability created by [Voidwalk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidwalk) triggered.
- The delayed triggered ability created by [Voidwalk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidwalk) was placed on the stack.
- Both players passed priority.
- The delayed triggered ability created by [Voidwalk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidwalk) started resolving, placing [Spark Trooper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Trooper) on the battlefield.

As such, [Spark Trooper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Trooper) wasn't even close to being on the battlefield at the beginning of the end step. It's ability won't trigger that turn.